# Avoid table header in "<th>" break in mutiple lines

Tags: html

My html code:

```
<table border="3">
<tr>
    <th>a a a</td>
    <th>bbb</td>
    <th>ccc</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</td>
    <td>ccc</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And what I get:

[image]

As you see, `a a a` breaks in three lines.

I can't use `aaa` instead of `a a a`(In fact, `a a a` in my case is `运营商`, and these three Chinese character will break as `a a a`).

You may debug it in http://jsfiddle.net/Kisnu/Lsubhd7q/.

Comment: All the "a"s show up on one line in your fiddle.

Comment: Also, there are errors in your HTML. You've ended your `<th>` tags with `</td>`.

Comment: @SkyBoydston It may depend on resolution of your monitor. I capture that picture from my `jsfiddle`. You may add more `b` in `bbb` column.

Comment: @SkyBoydston Oh, sorry for that, I will fix it. It's interesting that still works.

Comment: That's what I just noticed, too. If I shrink the frame of the fiddle then it'll break over the spaces. That may give a possible solution. Just restrict the minimum size of your columns, though I agree with @Lowkase that you need to provide valid dummy data, in this case Chinese chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want your headers to break at all you can use the following CSS rule:

`th {
    white-space: nowrap;
}`

Comment: Could you please tell me a little more about why that CSS works?

Comment: You are telling the content in the header cells not to line wrap.

Answer (score 0):

Lack of valid dummy data is making the table break in weird dimensions.

Try using more "valid" dummy data.  Unless the words in your data are literally 256 characters long without breaks then you are not using "real world" data.

Try using lorum ipsum to dummy up your data:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lsubhd7q/3/

```
<table border="3">
<tr>
    <th>Sed ut perspiciatis accusantium doloremque</td>
    <th>voluptatem accusantium doloremque</td>
    <th>iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque</td>
    <td>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque</td>
    <td>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque</td>
</tr>
</table>
```